# How to model arrival distribution which is non poisson?

Tags: anylogic

I am modelling a process where everyday certain x number arrives over a period of month. The arrival rate in anylogic assumes poission distribution. How we should go for no possion distribution ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is 1 way: switch to inter-arrival times and use any distribution you like:
[image]

Check out the "Probability distribution wizard" (see help) for more info on available distributions.

Also check custom distributions. And the help on "distributions"... :)

PS: Tons of options, many people asked this previously, use the search as well.